# JavaScript onClick async to firebase delete document

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

still pretty new to javascript and react.
I try to delete a post from firebase. I get my username, my docId and everything works fine instead of the last part. It won´t delete my post.

[image]

If I hardcore and fire it onClick it deletes what I want.

```
  firebase
        .database()
        .ref("posts/" + str2 + "posts/" + props.id)
        .remove();
```

.

```
onPress: async () => {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      const authUser = user.uid;
      var username = await firebase
        .database()
        .ref("users/" + authUser + "/name")
        .once("value")
        .then(function(snapshot) {
          return snapshot;
        });

      var myJSON = JSON.stringify(username);
      var str2 = myJSON.slice(1, -1);

      console.log("#######id", props.id);

      await firebase
        .database()
        .ref("posts/" + str2 + "posts/" + props.id)
        .remove();
    }
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your database?

Comment: Sure, updated my post.

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure that `"posts/" + str2 + "posts/" + props.id` does contain all the `/`? In particular the one between `str2` and `posts`

Comment: Thank you very much! Maybe I am too tired. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure! Have a nice day and stay healthy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the [`ref()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Database?authuser=0#ref) method, to define a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) representing a location in the Realtime Database, you need to pass a path that corresponds to your database JSON tree: the different child nodes shall be separated by a `/`.

So your code shall be adapted as follows:

```
  await firebase
    .database()
    .ref("posts/" + str2 + "/posts/" + props.id)
    .remove();
```