# JavaScript async remove firebase document

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that checks if bullet hits a player, and if so it should remove the bullet and the player that got hit.

I have `check_if_bullet_hit_player(bulletRef)` function that gets a bullet ref, and the id of the player got shot.

I also have a `shoot()` function that calls the `check_if_bullet_hit_player(bulletRef)` for every bullet's movement.

Currently when a bullet hits a player, the bullet disappear, but I can't make the player got hit to disappear also.

### **Attempt - 1:**

I tried the following `shoot` function:

```
function shoot(speed=0.5, distance=5, targetX, targetY){
 var shoot = setInterval(function() {
  check_if_bullet_hit_player(bulletRef).then(player_got_shot_id => {
     if (player_got_shot_id != ""){
       clearInterval(shoot); 
       bulletRef.remove();
       hitPlayerRef = firebase.database().ref(`players/${player_got_shot_id}`);
       hitPlayerRef.once("value").then(function(){
         alert("hi");
         hitPlayerRef.remove();
       })
     }
   })
 })
}
```

I get alert `hi` when a player gets hit, and the player that gets hit disappear for a moment, then re-created (which is not what is wanted). I think that the player get re-created because of async, so I tried different methods.

### **Attempt - 2:**

I tried as the [following stack overflow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60800762/javascript-onclick-async-to-firebase-delete-document), which waits for the ref to return:

```
function shoot(speed=0.5, distance=5, targetX, targetY){
 var shoot = setInterval(function() {
  check_if_bullet_hit_player(bulletRef).then(player_got_shot_id => {
     if (player_got_shot_id != ""){
       clearInterval(shoot); 
       bulletRef.remove();
      await firebase.database().ref(`players/${player_got_shot_id}`).remove();
     }
   })
 })
}
```

and I get:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`

### **Attempt - 3:**

I tried to wait with `then`:

```
function shoot(speed=0.5, distance=5, targetX, targetY){
 var shoot = setInterval(function() {
  check_if_bullet_hit_player(bulletRef).then(player_got_shot_id => {
     if (player_got_shot_id != ""){
       clearInterval(shoot); 
       bulletRef.remove();
       hitPlayerRef = firebase.database().ref(`players/${player_got_shot_id}`);
       return hitPlayerRef.get();  // HERE we chain the promise
     }
   }).then(hola => {
       hola.remove();
    })
 })
}
```

But nothing happens.

How can I make the player got hit to disappear?

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out how to help here, as there's too much going on. I recommend showing us only one implementation, the one that you think should've worked. I also recommend searching for any error message you get, as the one about `await` in `async functions` has been covered quite a few times before. Finally, we can't see what `check_if_bullet_hit_player` does. If that is important to the problem, include it in the question. If it isn't important, show a reproduction of the problem without that call.